# jQuery Validation Plugin

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-validate

I really was trying to avoid asking this question. I have seen quite a few posts on SO regarding this plugin but they still didn't quite get it for me. Right now I have a new account registration form and I'm trying to write a custom method for validating a unique username. I would like to think that the following should work:

```
$.validator.addMethod(
        "uniqueUsername", 
        function(value, element) {
            $.post(
                "http://" + location.host + "/scripts/ajax/check_username.php",
                {
                    username: value
                },
                function(response) {
                    if(response == 'true') {
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            );
        },
        "This username is already taken."
    );
```

Unfortunately it seems like the plugin moves on regardless of the callback function. I found someone suggest doing something like the following:

```
var result = false;
    $.validator.addMethod(
        "uniqueUsername", 
        function(value, element) {
            $.post(
                "http://" + location.host + "/scripts/ajax/check_username.php",
                {
                    username: value
                },
                function(response) {
                    if(response == 'true') {
                        result = true;
                    } else {
                        result = false;
                    }
                }
            );
            return result;
        },
        "This username is already taken."
    );
```

But it seems to have a delay since it stores the value, then on the next event will set whatever the value is. What do you guys recommend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is an asynchronous check, there needs to be more around it (you can't return a value from a function like this, it'll always be false in your case).  The built-in method is `remote`, used like this:

```
$("form").validate({
  rules: {
    username: {
      remote: {
        url: "http://" + location.host + "/scripts/ajax/check_username.php",
        type: "post"
      }
    }
  }  
});
```

This will POST a `username: valueofElement` since the rule is for the element named `username`.  Your server-side script should return `true` if the validation should pass, `false` otherwise...so `false` if the user name is already taken.

[You can read more about the `remote` option here](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/remote), including how to pass additional data arguments if needed.

Answer (score -1):

js code

```
username: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 5,
        remote: '/userExists'
       },
```

Php code to check if exist and return messages

```
public function userExists()
{
    $user = User::all()->lists('username');
    if (in_array(Input::get('username'), $user)) {
        return Response::json(Input::get('username').' is already taken');
    } else {
        return Response::json(Input::get('username').' Username is available');
    }
}
```

Comment: No good.  The PHP **must** `echo true` when you want validation to pass.  Any other response, such as a JSON string, indicates _failed_ validation.  Since the validation failed, the form cannot be submitted.   Also, not sure why you answered a four-year-old question that already has an accepted answer.